# jQuery UI Datepicker : _optionDatepicker() is not firing in IPAD

Tags: jquery, user-interface, datepicker

_optionDatepicker() is not firing in IPAD on touch of single digit for selecting date in datepicker control.

When i touch to select number 2 it does not work. When i select by touching double digit 10 it gets selected and the above function fires.

I'm using jQuery UI Datepicker 1.8.23

Comment: Try to post some code of what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

Add leading zeros to the single digits, i.e. 01, 02, etc.